# iOS click on dynamic UIButton crashes

Tags: ios, onclick, crash, uibutton, addtarget

I'm creating programmatically a UIButton with an Image.

```
UIButton * bericht = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.bounds.size.width- height, 0, height, height)];
[bericht setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bericht.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bericht addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:bericht];

- (void) imageClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
   NSLog(@"test message");
}
```

When I click on this button I got the following error code:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 
'-[__NSSetM goToFirstTrailer:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fdaf1e73fe0'
```

Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: where is goToFirstTrailer method being used?

Comment: Where is located this code. It looks like self = NSMutableSet

Comment: I assume, you execute goToFirstTrailer method of NSSet collection which doesn't have such method

Comment: Selector method spelling is different than its method. Replace `@selector(imageCLicked:)` with `@selector(imageClicked:)`. Do you get any warnings at that line?

Comment: We need I bit more code, in order to know height. I think, In your didSelectRowAtIndexPath: methods you call goToFirstTrailler: (but only when the film has been selected. Probably your mistake is the cellForRow methods doesn't know the cell dimensions, and you are thinking that you are creating you button in a place but it's out the screen, and didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is call when you don't want that. (But I say this like play a magic).

Comment: Its nothing more than a Method name capitalisation issue. Just copy your Method name & paste it to selector.

Comment: Stupid spelling misstake sorry. But changig to the same doesn't helped. Got the same error

Comment: I think hight is not the problem because the image is in the tablerow. The goToFirstTrailler was just e method trying to debug. In the didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method I'm not doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector method to imageClicked.

```
UIButton * bericht = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(tableView.bounds.size.width- height, 0, height, height)];

[bericht setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bericht.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bericht addTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.contentView addSubview:bericht];

- (void) imageClicked:(UIButton *) sender {
   NSLog(@"iaksdkjas");
}
```

Comment: doesn't change anything